# Java: Научный вид числа в стандартный

Tags: android, java

Java (Android).

Когда число (тип double) становится очень большим, при переводе в строку оно начинает вмещать буквы (в частности букву **Е** и т.д. и т.п.).

Как правильно переводить число в строку, чтобы оно было нормального вида?

Сейчас у меня так:

```
Double.toString(cost);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Заюзать [этот](http://javolution.org/target/site/apidocs/javolution/text/TypeFormat.html) метод:

```
TypeFormat.format(double d, int digits, boolean scientific, boolean showZero, Appendable a)
```

Или написать самому:

```
 private static String nosci(double d) {
    if(d < 0){
        return "-" + nosci(-d);
    }
    String javaString = String.valueOf(d);
    int indexOfE =javaString.indexOf("E"); 
    if(indexOfE == -1){
        return javaString;
    }
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    if(d > 1){
        int exp = Integer.parseInt(javaString.substring(indexOfE + 1));
        String sciDecimal = javaString.substring(2, indexOfE);
        int sciDecimalLength = sciDecimal.length();
        if(exp == sciDecimalLength){
            sb.append(javaString.charAt(0));
            sb.append(sciDecimal);              
        }else if(exp > sciDecimalLength){
            sb.append(javaString.charAt(0));
            sb.append(sciDecimal);
            for(int i = 0; i < exp - sciDecimalLength; i++){
                sb.append('0');
            }
        }else if(exp < sciDecimalLength){
            sb.append(javaString.charAt(0));
            sb.append(sciDecimal.substring(0, exp));
            sb.append('.');
            for(int i = exp; i < sciDecimalLength ; i++){
                sb.append(sciDecimal.charAt(i));
            }
        }
      return sb.toString();
    }else
        return javaString;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Для форматирование вывода (и не только числового) в Java предусмотрена целая иерархия классов с общим предком `java.text.Format`.

В интересующем вас варианте надо смотреть в сторону [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) - JavaDoc достаточно подробный и с примерами.

Не надо изобретать разнообразные "костыли"